# How to search for non-ASCII characters with bash tools?

Tags: bash, unicode, grep

I have a large text file that contains a few unicode characters that make LaTeX crash. How can I find non-ASCII characters in a file with sed, and the like in a Linux bash?

Comment: Is it a file in UTF-8, with the majority of characters being ASCII, but some are well-formed multi-byte UTF-8 and some are broken (multi-byte) UTF-8? Are there many well-formed (multi-byte) UTF-8 characters?  Or is it some other encoding entirely?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try:

```
nonascii() { LANG=C grep --color=always '[^ -~]\+'; }
```

Which can be used like:

```
printf 'ŨTF8\n' | nonascii
```

Within `[]` `^` means "not". So `[^ -~]` means characters not between space and ~. So excluding control chars, this matches non ASCII characters, and is a more portable though slightly less accurate version of `[^\x00-\x7f]` below. The `\+` means `1 or more` and will get multibye characters to have a color shown around the complete character(s), rather than interspersed in each byte, thus corrupting the multibyte sequence

Comment: can you explain me what '[^ -~]\+' means? ^ is start of line afaik.

Comment: Very nice. But control characters (except newline) are found, though they are indeed ASCII. So when there are tabs, carriage-returns (dos files), those are found. Can you provide an alternative which only prints non-ASCII characters? The `[^\x00-\x7f]` approach in the other answer doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Super useful! Cheers :)

Answer (score 30):

Try this command:

```
grep -P '[^\x00-\x7f]' file
```

Comment: @JonasStein Please add `-P`(--perl-regex) option.

Comment: Note: the `-P` option does not work in BSD grep, which is the one shipped in OSX

Comment: @nacho4d What can one do instead then?

Comment: simply skip it. for example: `grep  '[^\x00-\x7f]' file`