# Search unicode character in R package/.Rd file

Tags: r, unicode, rstudio

How can I search for a specific unicode character in an R package or a specific file (I am using the RStudio IDE).

I am trying to submit a package to CRAN. All checks pass except for:

```
W  checking PDF version of manual (49.5s)
   LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
   This typically indicates Rd problems.
   LaTeX errors found:
   ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+008D)
   (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

So when all Rd files are compiled to one pdf there seems to be a problematic character.
To fix this I need to go through all my .Rd files and find character U+008D, the [reverse line feed character](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+008D)).

Since it is sort of a sneaky character, I am not sure if the RStudio editor even displays it.

Any ideas?

### Notes:

- I have no control over the latex engine, as the error occurs on one of CRANs machines

Comment: If you are on linux, maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596531/how-to-search-for-non-ascii-characters-with-bash-tools

Comment: I am on Windows but I have a virtual linus machine. Just hoping there was a way within RStudio... I'll try

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a direct answer to my question, I'll answer to explain where the error occured.

The problem was a bibtex entry. I'm using the [Rdpack](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rdpack/index.html) package to include bibtex entries in my .Rd files.

One of the entries had a symbol that bibtex didnt like (some accent character). Removing the character in the bibtex file fixed it.