# Text line contains an invalid character

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, tex

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis using Rmarkdown, and whenever i make changes I knit to PDF to check how it looks etc.
It worked perfectly until I wanted to check some small changes and after that I can´t get it to knit, this is the error message I get:

```
output file: bbb.knit.md

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.28 pdftitle={^^K
space{3.5in} Portfolio},

Error: Failed to compile bbb.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See bbb.log for more info.
```

Bare in mind that I am learning R while writing my thesis so I do have a very low level of knowledge. Does anyone have any suggestions for where the mistake might be? Line 28 has no text by the way.
I have read some suggestions about deleting the auxiliary file but I dont even know what that is or where to find it, or if it could cause me any problems deleting it.

Hope someone has some tips as wasting a lot of time on this is the last I need right now! Thanks

Comment: Go to the folder where your `*.Rmd` file is in and check if there is the `*.log` file and delete it.

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]? This would safe us from wasting a lot of time trying to reproduce your problem!

Comment: Imagine you're looking for a UTF-8 that is also set to invisible (doesn't show in console), Saw this recently with a problem submitting a package to CRAN. So a search on that problem in the past 10 days might get your there. HTH

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried deleting the *.log file but it did not change anything. I did find the solution by chance, which was to remove the YAML title input from "\vspace{3.5in} Portfolio" to only "Portfolio". Not at all sure about why seeing that it worked well this morning. But its all good now!

Comment: the referred UTF-8 [remove char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60901844/search-unicode-character-in-r-package-rd-file). AND write up your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change the title input in YAML from "\vspace{3.5in} Portfolio"
to only "Portfolio".

Comment: and perhaps an issue at RMarkdown github, as this probably be more generally handled?

Comment: If you had that string literally, the problem is that "\v" is a control character.  You probably should have had "\\vspace{3.5in} Portfolio", because in R you need to double the backslash to escape it.